# Ping not working from Windows to Linux

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, ubuntu, ping

I have a fresh Ubuntu system that I am trying to ssh into from another PC. I'm starting out just trying to see if I can get a Windows system to see my Ubuntu system so I am using ping.

Here is my configuration:

- PC A (Ubuntu 15.10)
- PC B (Windows 8)
- PC C (Windows 7)

and these are the results of testing:

- PC A can ping PC B
- PC A can ping PC C
- PC B cannot ping either A or C
- PC C cannot ping either A or B
- All PCs can ping www.google.com

I have turned off all firewalls and anti-virus applications.

Comment: What is your networking setup?  Everything in a small area using Wi-Fi? Wired? (How?)  In your local ping commands, are you using host names (A, B, and C) or the corresponding IP addresses?  (Are all machines using IPv4?)  What error messages are you getting?  Have you gotten any other type of network connectivity to work?

Comment: I am currently using Wi-Fi but am moving PC A to wired soon. IPv4 was what I pinged with on all machines and I used the IPs not pc names or anything. I am not getting an error message per se, but I am getting connection timed out every 3 seconds or so for each packet sent. The only other networking I have gotten working is as I mentioned PC A can ping everything else with success and Internet access on all machines.